# how to generate xml file using gSOAP with Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, salesforce, gsoap

I am using gSOAP, Visual C++ connecting to salesforce.com and I am very new to gSOAP.
I am retrieving some data using SOAP.
Are there any ways to generate the SOAP result to a xml file?
If anyone has got some sample codes, it would be very helpful for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations on getting this far :)

I'm not providing a solution, but a workaround:
Compile with the *DEBUG* flag and gSoap will produce three log files. One of these - "RECV.log" - will contain entire response, including the XML file.

However, gSoap does entire response parsing for you, so it is probably much easier to just gather relevant data from the response structure it provides.